# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently right now I am trying to combine a list of Domains with a specific path. When trying to combine the domains with a specific path I am getting the error.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'unicode

I am currently reading from two excel documents. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib


apps = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", "Sheet1")
pdirs= pd.read_excel("dirs.xlsx", "Sheet1")

urls = apps['Domains'].values.tolist()
dirs = pdirs['DIR'].values.tolist() 

for websites in urls:
    for directory in dirs:
        testURL= websites + directory
        print (testURL)
```

The websites are formatted such as test.test.com and the directory variables will be formatted like /test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the error. You cannot sum a float (number) and a unicode (string). Apparently, `websites` variable has a float value and `directory` has a string.

Answer (score 0):

you better typecast it. I mean
`str(websites) + str(directory)`